# Sqoop Installation with hadoop 2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to install all apache hadoop components in my system. I installed hadoop-2.2.0, hive-0.11.0, pig-0.12.0, hbase-0.96.0, now its time to install sqoop. So please suggest me installation steps of sqoop which is compatable with hadoop-2.2.0 and hbase.

Hope for reply soon
thanks in advance for reply back.

Answer (score 2):

@Naveen:The link that you have provided is for Sqoop2.It is not specifically for Hadoop 2.0 branch.Basically it tries to resolve and enhance Sqoop by changing the design to client server model(i.e it's major promises include ease of use,ease of extension,security).For more details,find this interesting video for sqoop2 @https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg683-GOWP4.

We can use the latest Sqoop(version 1.4.4(compiled library for hadoop2.0) or 1.4.5) from ASF.Just download the correct version of sqoop for hadoop 2.0 branch.For e.g sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz can be downloaded and used without any issue with Hadoop 2.0+ versions.

If you couldn't find sqoop version(I assume you are using versions earlier than 1.4.4) for Hadoop2.0 + from the ASF site,you have to recompile the sqoop source code for hadoop 2.0 branch.But it is not required since you can just use the latest sqoop version which supports hadoop 2.0(Hope you are not looking for production ready sqoop version for hadoop 2.0 since the recent versions of sqoop for hadoop2 is still in alpha phase!!!)

I haven't tried Sqoop2 yet.It will also help with the new enhancements for all Hadoop versions 1.0,2.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try These steps for installation of sqoop with hadoop 2.2.0

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.1/Installation.html